# Microsoft Access Database Item doesn't go away from right click (Context) menu

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, context-menu, regedit

I'm wanting to remove ***"Microsoft Access Database"*** from the ***"New"*** subsection of the context menu in Windows 10, [just like in this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/Cp-KtkAD090?t=20).

[Image of Context menu displaying ***"Microsoft Access Database"*** after I attempted to remove it, shown in the Registry Editor in the background(".accdb" is the file type for "Microsoft Access Database" files.) files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REdEZ.png)

[Now, when I click Microsoft Access Database, instead of adding an icon to the Desktop,what I would call the "home page" for Microsoft Access Database opens, along with file explorer, which I closed before taking the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SeH5.png)

[This image shows Microsoft PowerPoint edited in the Registry Editor and removed from the Right click (Context) menu, to show that Microsoft programs were able to be removed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw7Z1.jpg)

After "Microsoft Access Database" wasn't removed from the menu, I did restart my machine, and it was still there.

Any suggestions, and if possible without downloading any software? Though if downloading is the only way to go, then alright.

Comment: https://blogs.systweak.com/best-context-menu-editors-for-windows/

Comment: Check if the registry was rebuilt after rebooting Windows. You can refer to  [How to Add or Remove Items from “New” Context Menu in Windows](https://www.askvg.com/how-to-add-remove-items-from-new-menu-in-windows/) .